# react-phone-number-input validation with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

phone-number-input](https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input#readme) with [react-hook-form](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form) and it works normally. I want to validate the phone number with isValidPhoneNumber from react-phone-number-input  but I do not know how to achieve that with react-hook-form.  I have read some posts here about this problem but there's no correct answer for me. Here is my code:

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import PhoneInput, { isValidPhoneNumber } from 'react-phone-number-input'

import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'

const MyForm = () => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control,
  } = useForm()

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="user-info-form">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="phone-input">Phone Number</label>
        <Controller
          name="phone-input"
          control={control}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <PhoneInput
              value={value}
              onChange={onChange}
              defaultCountry="TH"
              id="phone-input"
            />
          )}
        />
        {errors.phone && <p className="error-message">Invalid Phone</p>}
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default MyForm
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing `isValidPhoneNumber` method for the `validate` key of the `rules` prop of the controller.

And you have done a typo as well. In your the `Controller` name is `phone-input`. So, you have to check for the `phone-input` key in the `errors` object instead of `phone`.

Please find the answer.

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import PhoneInput, { isValidPhoneNumber } from "react-phone-number-input";

import "react-phone-number-input/style.css";

const MyForm = () => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control
  } = useForm();


  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="user-info-form">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="phone-input">Phone Number</label>
        <Controller
          name="phone-input"
          control={control}
          rules={{
            validate: (value) => isValidPhoneNumber(value)
          }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <PhoneInput
              value={value}
              onChange={onChange}
              defaultCountry="TH"
              id="phone-input"
            />
          )}
        />
        {errors["phone-input"] && (
          <p className="error-message">Invalid Phone</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: Have to change  `rules={{ validate: (value) => isValidPhoneNumber(value) }}...` to  `rules={{validate: (value) => isPossiblePhoneNumber(\`${value}\`)}}` cause of this error : `parsePhoneNumber.js:18 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: A text for parsing must be a string`